# SDL Missing recording device

Tags: c, audio, sdl, sdl-2

I have 2 audio recording devices available in my PC, namely Stereo mix and Speakers. I can use both of them through Audacity program as shown here[image]

But when I enumerate recording devices in SDL only one of them is listed[image]

by running the following code.

```
SDL_version v;
SDL_GetVersion(&v);
printf("SDL version %d.%d.%d\n", v.major, v.minor, v.patch);

int a= SDL_GetNumAudioDevices(1);
for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
    printf("%s\n",SDL_GetAudioDeviceName(i, 1));
```

How can I access the other device as well in SDL?

Comment: I'm under impression that SDL2 doesn't support audio recording at all, and devices it prints are playback devices. Maybe try a different library, e.g. OpenAL?

Comment: What's your SDL audio driver (`SDL_GetCurrentAudioDriver`)? I take it your second device is emulated virtual device?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Is OpenAL available for the Mingw compiler too? I can't seem to find the corresponding link file anywhere (libopenal.a). the OpenAL SDK provides link files for Visual Studio only.

Comment: @keltar I used that command you mentioned and the output is "wasapi" as audio driver

Comment: @Tristan for what I see loopback is a virtual device that records full system output as an input. Quick search suggests audio needs to be initialised with `AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_LOOPBACK`, which SDL (and I suspect pretty much every other game-oriented library) don't do. If you really need that functionality, I suppose you'll have to use WASAPI directly.

Comment: You can build it yourself: https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Audio capture's been in since 2.0.5.